# CQ5 Get page full path in Servlet from cut url

Tags: servlets, aem, sling

Got a problem - on the server where CQ is run there used IIS dispatcher to make pages accessible with the short url. It results as follows: you can skip several parts of url; for example, instead of `site.com/en/department/unit/country/topic/page.html` can adress `site.com/country/topic/page.html`.

I've got a `SlingAllMethodsServlet` servlet, that needs full page path to store some data about the page (like number of visitors, likes, etc.) as it identifies the page. But when the servlet is called from a page with shorten url, all info I can get from SlingHttpServletRequest and Resolver returns this cut path, while I need it to be full.

So my question is - is there a way to get a full page path in this case in `SlingAllMethodsServlet` when the path to page is cut by dispatcher? Or is there a way to get this information from some JS objects so I could pass in as a parameter to the servlet?

Thanks

Comment: From within the SlingAllMethodsServlet, can you not simply call `request.getResource().getPath()` — this should give you the unmapped path of the underlying resource.

Comment: And you can then use page manager to get page path. request.getResourceResolver().adaptTo(PageManager.class).getContainingPage(request.getResource()).getPath()